# How to make a smart contract/ a third party pay for transaction fees?

Tags: contract-deployment, contract-invocation, fees, staking

I'm trying to create a LiquidStacking smart contract where it would be possible to deposit any amount of ETH. Every time the smart contract's balance reach 32 ETH, it creates a BeaconChainDepositor smart contract to deposit the 32 ETH on the Beacon Chain.

Is it possible to make the LiquidStacking contract pay the BeaconChainDepositor smart contract creation and invocation fees?

```
contract LiquidStacking {

    function depositEth() payable external {
        // Mint LST.....
        if (address(this).balance >= 32 ether) {
            BeaconChainDepositor beaconChainDepositor = new BeaconChainDepositor{value: 32 ethers};
            beaconCHainDepositor.activateValidator();
        }  
    }
}
```

That wouldn't be fair if the last staker has to pay the fees for the smart contract creation and invocation.

Do someone knows how could make the LiquidStacking contracts or an other account pay the fees?

Thank you very much!!

Comment: I apologise for the misunderstanding. That’s why I’ve deleted my answer. You can have a third party, such as a common wallet, pay the fees for such transactions. However, this cannot be done directly through smart contract code; instead, it requires utilizing frontend functionality in your corresponding dApp. [This post](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/162076/trying-to-create-a-dapp-where-transactions-are-signed-by-a-default-wallet) might be helpful for achieving that.