# Trying to create a dApp where transactions are signed by a default wallet

Tags: ethers.js, private-key, web3-providers

I am making a casino for a client and I want all data of amount won by a user to be sent to my contract. The gas for each of these "data sending transactions" will be approved by the client's wallet which will pay for the gas so the users don't have to

```js
async function sendToContract() {
    try {
      const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum);
      const wallet = new ethers.Wallet(privateKey);
  
      const signer = wallet.connect(provider); 
  
      const contract = new ethers.Contract(contractAddress, abi, signer);
      console.log("Contract:", contract);
  
      await contract.setWithdrawAmount(ethers.utils.parseEther(String(user.unclaimed)), user.walletId).then((res) => {
         console.log(res)
      }).catch((err) => {
            console.log(err)
      });
  
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
}
```

This code is in the frontend, so I could use `window.ethereum` but even though the transaction instance is created and I am getting a response of the data being sent on `.then((res))` , the transaction is not finally being sent to the blockchain

Any help on this?

Answer (score 0):

You might have to wait for the **transaction receipt** to be generated from the **signed transaction**, like:

```js
await contract.setWithdrawAmount(ethers.utils.parseEther(String(user.unclaimed)), user.walletId).then(async (signedTx) => {
   const txReceipt = await signedTx.wait();
   console.log("Transaction hash: ", txReceipt.transactionHash);
}).catch((err) => {
   console.log(err)
});
```

I've created a minimal example for end-to-end testing.

**Contract:**

```js
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.24;

contract Test {

    uint256 public unclaimed;
    address public walletId;

    function setWithdrawAmount(uint256 _unclaimed, address _walletId) external {
        unclaimed = _unclaimed;
        walletId = _walletId;
    }
}
```

**JS Function (In Frontend dApp):**

```js
async function sendToContract() {
    try {
        const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum);
        const privateKey = 'CLIENT_WALLET_KEY'
        const wallet = new ethers.Wallet(privateKey);

        const signer = wallet.connect(provider);

        const contractAddress = "0x71ebf352Ce4b3fCb851c2A171e7f05E78937ddaf"
        const abi = [{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"_unclaimed","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address","name":"_walletId","type":"address"}],"name":"setWithdrawAmount","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"unclaimed","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"walletId","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"}]
        const contract = new ethers.Contract(contractAddress, abi, signer);
        //   console.log("Contract:", contract);
        const user = {
            unclaimed: 10,
            walletId: signer.address  // Passing in the address corresponding to client's private key for testing
        }

        console.log(user)

        await contract.setWithdrawAmount(ethers.utils.parseEther(String(user.unclaimed)), user.walletId).then(async (signedTx) => {
            const txReceipt = await signedTx.wait();
            console.log("Transaction hash: ", txReceipt.transactionHash);
        }).catch((err) => {
            console.log(err)
        });

    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
}
```

You can see the successful transactions that have occurred for the [deployed contract](https://mumbai.polygonscan.com/address/0x71ebf352ce4b3fcb851c2a171e7f05e78937ddaf).